# Eclipse doesn't work correctly when not run as super user

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse from Eclipse page and extracted it in Downloads directory. When I run Eclipse as normal user then application behaves strange:

```
$ ./eclipse
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Some symptoms:

- Eclipse can't resolve symbols in source code and marks them as invalid
- GUI looks like in other KDE applications
- when I quit program, then there is some error about write protection

Error message:

```
Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench.
Could not write metadata for '/ab'.
/home/user/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/ab/.markers (Permission denied)
```

I encountered some other problems like write problems during update.

However when I run Eclipse as super user:

```
$ sudo ./eclipse
```

then everything works as it should and GUI looks different (GTK is loaded or what? I don't know).

I tried to give 777 permission to all files in Eclipse directory but it didn't work. And I didn't install Eclipse anywhere, just downloaded and extracted. I tried also to download Eclipse with apt-get but there was the same problem. How to make Eclipse work correct?

I use Kubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the permissions on your workspace are messed up?  Usually that's in ~/workspaces, so if you do a chown -R on that tree, it might help.

Comment: Operation not permitted error..

Answer (score 0):

I think that [you should use gksudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) (kdesudo on Kubuntu) to run graphical applications.

Answer (score 0):

Using an administrator account, in the console type:

```
sudo chown user:user /home/user/workspace -R
```

Remember to replace **user** with the username you wish to use eclipse.

Also keep in mind running eclipse as root will possibly create new files in the workspace directory that can be updated/deleted only by the root user, meaning the error you're experiencing.

Comment: he doesn't ask how to run eclipse as a superuser, but how to repair it to run it as usual user without issues:)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to include the chown command.